# How to add autosuggest to my searchbar?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to add an autosuggest function to my searchbar using jquery. But I'm unsuccessful in my attempts. I've followed the tutorials but still don't get it.

The hide().show(2000) works on my searchbar but not the rest. What have I missed?

EDIT: I've kept digging for solutions and still no luck. I've edited my code with my new changes. I've found that function online at https://goodies.pixabay.com/jquery/auto-complete/demo.html and it works on their site.

EDIT2: I've managed to get it to work as a stand alone site. Is it possible that something is blocking it on my real site? If so, how can I overwrite the block?

```
$(function(){
$('#search').autoComplete({
    minChars: 2,
    source: function(term, suggest){
        term = term.toLowerCase();
        var choices = ['ActionScript', 'AppleScript', 'Asp', ...];
        var matches = [];
        for (i=0; i<choices.length; i++)
            if (~choices[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(term)) matches.push(choices[i]);
        suggest(matches);
    }
});
});
```

My html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Testsite</title>

  <script>"jQuery-autoComplete-master/jquery.auto-complete.min.js"</script>
  <script>"jQuery-autoComplete-master/jquery.auto-complete.js"</script>
  <script>"jQuery-autoComplete-master/jquery.auto-complete.css"</script>

</head>
<body>
    <div>
            <h1>Search field</h1>
    <input id="search" style="width: 500px; height: 50px;font-size:18pt;" placeholder="ActionScript or AppleScript"><br>
    <div id="results"></div>
    <p></p>


    <!--<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script>
        //function for autocomplete
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Why you adding 2 different version of jQuery added in your html?

Comment: Adding scripts with the `src` set to a relative path is useless on StackOverlow. Also, your first `jQuery` is served over `http` and will be rejected as `Mixed Content`, if you the rest is served over `https`. Finally, you haven't included the `autocomplete` plugin.

Answer (score 2):

I deduced, from the two jQuery imports, that you were looking for the `autocomplete()` from the jQuery UI function, not jQuery.

If this is the case, you just need to add their JS, and preferably their CSS as well. Otherwise, you need to add the code for the `autocomplete()` function you want to use!

Your code, editing the includes:

```js
$(function() {
  var availableTutorials = [
    "ActionScript",
    "Bootstrap",
    "C",
    "C++",
  ];

  $('#search').hide(0).show(2000);
  $("#search").autocomplete({
    source: availableTutorials
  });
});
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Sök efter en bok</h1>
  <input id="search" style="width: 500px; height: 50px;font-size:18pt;" placeholder="Titel"><br>
  <button id="button" type="button">Sök bok</button>
  <div id="results"></div>
  <p></p>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <!--<script src="js/seekBook.js"></script>-->
</div>
```

Ps: Next time, please provide everything in English and without inaccessible code (example: `seekBook.js`). Your question and my answer should apply to everyone, not only your case ;)